# WordPress custom drop-down menu

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu

I am looking to build a customisable drop-down menu in WP (using css styles I have already created) , where the user is able to add and subtract page headings to the drop downs by creating categories on the WP menu page. So far I have managed to do this for a more straight forward sub-navigation menu and pointing the code to that, as follows:

```
<nav id="sub-navigation">
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Sub Nav Menu')); ?>
</nav>
```

The same code is not picking up the styles for the main-navigation drop-downs and I would like some help as to why this is so. I can publish the full code if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have menu style in html is as follows:

```
<div id="menu-container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>menu1</li>
    <li>menu2</li>
    <li>menu3</li>
    <li>menu4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And your functions.php has

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'Primary' => __( 'Primary Menu' )
        )
    );
}
```

now the code will be for menu is:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
            'theme_location' => 'Primary', 
            'menu_id' => '', 
            'menu_class' => 'nav', 
            'container_id' =>'menu-container',
            'container_class' =>''
));?>
```

to catch the css rules for drop down menu item, you can use in your css

```
.nav ul
.nav ul li
.nav ul li a
```

or

```
.sub-menu ul
.sub-menu ul li
.sub-menu ul li a
```

See my client site: [gift ideas](http://giftideasitems.com/)
to get an idea.
hope it helps.